# Виртуальное наследование: проблема с вызовом конструктора с параметрами при создании объекта

Tags: наследование, c++

При ромбовидном наследовании не вызывается **конструктор с параметрами**, при создании объекта производного. Т.е. если в мэйне будет:

```
D object (1, 'c', .99, "");
cout << object;
```

то в таком случает вместо желаемого вызова A(N), который по логике должен вызываться согласно цепочке, вызывает конструктор без параметров. Сама мини-иерархия:

```
class A
{
public:
    A () {}
    A (int N) : n (N) {}
protected:
    int n;
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B () : A () {}
    B (int N, char C) : A (N), c (C) {}
protected:
    char c;
};

class C : virtual public A
{
public:
    C () : A () {}
    C (int N, double D) : A (N), d(D) {}
protected:
    double d;
};

class D : public B, public C
{
public:
    D () : B (), C () {}
    D (int N, char C, double D, char* Str) : C (N, D), B (N, C) { strcpy (str, Str); }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const D& operand)
    {
        out << operand.n << " " << operand.c << " " << operand.d << " " << operand.str << endl;
        return out;
    }

    friend istream& operator >> (istream& in, D& operand)
    {
        cout << "int : ";
        cin >> operand.n;
        cout << "char : ";
        cin >> operand.c;
        cout << "double : ";
        cin >> operand.d;
        cout << "string : ";
        cin >> operand.str;
        return in;
    }

protected:
    char str[20];
};
```

Извините, конечно, за простейший вопрос, но я не могу разобраться =)

Comment: А что, собственно, не работает? Т.е., я вижу проблему, но хочу уточнить

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись.
Т.к. не вызывается конструктор с параметрами у самого базового, то первый параметр, который я передаю конструктору при создании объекта object класса D в главной функции не инициализирует член n самого базового класса.

Comment: т.е. на выходе я получаю объект с неинициализированным членом, а именно int n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

И не получится. На то оно и виртуальное наследование. Конструктор базового класса при виртуальном наследовании надо  вызывать явно

```
class D{
.........
D (int N, char C, double D, char* Str) : C (D), B (C), A(N) { strcpy (str, Str); }
.........
};
```

Comment: Дабы не создавать отдельный вопрос.
Записывая созданный объект в бинарный файл, я спокойно его читаю и могу работать с объектом, в который считал содержимое файла. НО стойт мне выйти из программы и запустить ее заново, не удаляя тот бинарный файл, то я не могу его уже считать содержимое старого файла во временный объект. Вылетает критическая ошибка при чтении временного объекта.

Comment: Лучше задайте отдельным вопросом.